# Send data to controller with form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, form-for

Let's say I have a model `Factory` which `has_many` `Employees`.

In my view, I have the following :

```
%h3
  = @factory.name

%h3 Add new employee :
= form_for :employee do |f|
  .field
    = f.label "Name :"
    = f.text_field :name
  .field
    = f.label "Age :"
    = f.text_field :age
  .actions
    = f.submit 'Save new employee'
```

In my controller, I want to retreive the `id` of the variable `@factory` which was in the view. How can I access it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two way to do that first is creating nested routes http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

```
resources :factories do
  resources :employees
end
```

or create a hidden_field for that and assign its value to it

Answer (score 1):

On the controller that renders the form create a `@employee` instance, associated to the `@factory`

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @factory = Factory.find params[:id]
    @employee = @factory.employees.build
  end
end
```

And on the view use the instance `@employee` instead of `:employee`

```
= form_for @employee do |f|
  ...
```